# Can I choose the name of my jpa repository?

Tags: spring, repository, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have to name my interface that extends the CrudRepository
with a spacific name (I use spring and Jpa)
i.e.

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {}
```

so in this case I have a Entity with name UserRepository

I tried annotation

```
@Entity(name="UserCustomRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {}
```

but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible according to the documentation, see [*1.3.3.1. XML Configuration*](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.spring):

> Each of these beans will be registered under a bean name that is derived from the interface name, so an interface of `UserRepository` would be registered under `userRepository`.

Why do you need a custom name? Besides your example with `@Entity(name="UserCustomRepository")` is completely broken, `@Entity` is used to mark JPA entities, not Spring beans/repositories.

Comment: Because I have 2 datasources and I have the same name for some table in the two different database. So I'd like to have the name of repository with the name i.e. User -> UserRepository , but if It's not possible I'll do User -> UserRemoteRepository.TNX...

Comment: @Shinigami: Seems like your use-case is legitimate. If indeed it's not possible, consider [filling feature request](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA)